# Does Phaser Arcade.Body velocity include deltaTime or not?

Tags: phaser-framework

I want to move my character along the x axis with constantly speed. I thought move depends on frame rate. So, technically I should write

```
sprite.body.velocity.x = speed * deltaTime
```

where `deltaTime = game.time.elapsedMS / 1000;`

But if I'm doing that - my character moves vvvvverrry slooow, even if `speed = 1000`.

But if I'm writing

```
sprite.body.velocity.x = speed
```

it works fine. My fps = 60;

---

[Phaser Documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.8/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#velocity)
says:

> **velocity** - The velocity, or rate of change in speed of
>   the Body. Measured in pixels per second.

no deltatime....

and all demos do not have deltatime

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/platformer-basics

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/asteroids-movement

etc.

So, I don't understand: shoud I calculate deltaTime or just use `velocity.x`?

Comment: "velocity" is not coordinates displacement. Velocity should be always the same if you need object to move smoothly (without acceleration/deceleration) so no need to recalculate it for delta time or FPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.... I think I'm stupid...

My calculation of the `deltaTime` was wrong

The correct formula will be

```
deltaTime = (elapsedMS * fps) / 1000
```

[elapsedMS](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#elapsedMS) - The time in ms since the last time update, in milliseconds, based on time.

[fps](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#fps) - Frames per second.
(Only calculated if [advancedTiming](http://phaser.io/docs/2.5.0/Phaser.Time.html#advancedTiming) is enabled).

So, that was my problem.

---

As the result

[body.velocity](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.8/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.Body.html#velocity) doesn't include calculation of deltaTime and for smooth movement should use deltaTime that calculated by the formula above.

And it will be something like that

```
function update() { // <-- it is phaser state method...is called every frame
    deltaTime = (elapsedMS * fps) / 1000;
    sprite.body.velocity.x = velocityX * deltaTime;
    sprite.body.velocity.y = velocityY * deltaTime;
}
```